# Field types error when ribbon is shown

Tags: upgrade, ribbon

We upgraded our MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010 yesterday. Everything seemed fine until I chose Show Ribbon from the site menu.

Now I get an error like this: "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields"

And there is some more detail related to this error in ULS:

> *System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete
>   these fields.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXm...    d2c112c4-8af3-4d76-8aab-dc1a9d58468b*

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I think this is something about publishing infrastructure, because I get the same error when I try to navigate to Manage Content and Structure page.